# How to fold all paragraph in vim

Tags: vim, fold

I know "zfap" command, and it can fold a paragraph.

But how can I fold all paragraph? Is there a magic command can do this job?

I search "global" command, but "global" seems to work only for line mode , How can I do something in all paragraph one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:set fde=getline(v:lnum)=~'^\\s*$'&&getline(v:lnum+1)=~'\\S'?'<1':1
:set fdm=expr
```

Comment: Cf. the third example under the `:help fold-expr` section.

Comment: Thank you.  The fold expression is too diffcult to me, but it works.

Comment: @textpattern:  I have explained this very fold expression [answering](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5980322/254635) the question "[Explaining foldexpr syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5977895/254635)".